# Xamarin Android release .apk error in visual studio 2015

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I'm working with Xamarin Android and I want to export apk file in Visual Studio 2015. I use "Archive" feature in "Build" option on navigation bar of Visual Studio 2015. I exported apk file success but when I install it on device, it happens error

> Parse Error : There is a problem parsing the package

Anyone can help me? Thanks!!!

Comment: Please provide some more information. Is it running in an emulator? What are the properties of the device? Is it the package compatible with the Android version on the device? Do you have enough permission to install third-party apps from unknown sources? Exists security apps which block the install?

Answer (score 1):

This error can be caused by various reasons, but you can check a few things to make sure you have generated the correct apk file:

1. Please make sure you have signed the apk file. You can refer to [Manually Signing the APK](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_2_-_signing_the_android_application_package/manually-signing-the-apk/) for details about signing an apk file.
2. Please check the [CPU Architectures](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/cpu_architectures/) of your apk file.
3. If the error persists, please try use `adb install apkFileName.apk` to install the apk. The error message will be shown if the installation fails. You can find the adb under `AndroidSDKFolder\platform-tools\adb.exe`.